# How can I put the Constraints on Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment with two TextViews and an ImageView and I want to put the constraints to this views. 
How can I do it? Because I have only margins on Fragments, but I can't see the Layout Constraints on Attributes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".saludoscongratulationsfragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Lección completada!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
   />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fuegosartificiales"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="386dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the `constraintlayout` dependencies? If you have done it, you can use the `Constraintlayout` in your .xml file directly.

Comment: Hello Mauro, a FrameLayout can only display one view (if you add more, they will stack). What you'd want to do is replace your root "FrameLayout" with a `ConstraintLayout` (read more about it [in the official ConstraintLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)).